# Irreducible components of the curve-Algebraic set

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-curves

In my lecture notes I have the following:

$f, g \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$

$V(f)=V(g)$ if $f=p_1^{a_1} \cdot p_2^{a_2} \cdot \dots \cdot p_s^{a_s} , g=p_1^{b_1} \cdot p_2^{b_2} \cdot \dots \cdot p_s^{b_s}$, where $p_i(x,y)$ are the irreducible polynomials of $f, g$.

Definition: The curves that are defined by $p_i(x, y)$ are called irreducible components of the curve $f$ of multiplicity $a_i$.

It stands that $$V(f)=V(p_1) \cup V(p_2) \cup \dots \cup V(p_s)$$

What does it mean "the curves that are defined by $p_i(x, y)$" ?

Why does it stand that $V(f)=V(p_1) \cup V(p_2) \cup \dots \cup V(p_s)$ ? It is $V(f)=V(p_1^{a_1} \cdot p_2^{a_2} \cdot \dots \cdot p_s^{a_s}) \overset{ V(I \cdot J)=V(I) \cup V(J)}{ = }V(p_1^{a_1}) \cup V(p_2^{a_2}) \cup \dots \cup V(p_s^{a_s})$ or not?

Comment: "The curves defined by $p_i$" means the curve $V(p_i)$ and yes it is your last equally plus the fact that as varieties $V(p) = V(p^n)$ for any polynomial since $p=0$ if and only if $p^n = 0$.

Comment: I understand the second one! @DoriBejleri For the first one, both $f$ and $V(f)$ are curves?

Comment: No, $f$ is a polynomial. $V(f)$ is the curve. People just commonly drop saying "The curve defined by" and just refer to $f$ and $V(f)$ interchangeably. The curve is the geometric object defined as the solutions to the algebraic equation $f = 0$.

Comment: I am a little confused now, because in my lecture notes I found the following: "An algebraic curve in $\mathbb{C}^2$, is a polynomial $f(x, y( \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$. $V9F)$ is called the vanishing set of the curve $f$." @DoriBejleri Can you clarify it to me?